# Why is wrong bit representation got by converting byte array to BitSet in Java

Tags: java, bitset

I tried to convert a byte array in order to use its bit representation.

**Input:**

```
byte[] values = new byte[]{21, 117, 41, -1};
```

I would like to create one BitSet object from the byte array but I splitted up it to investigate the issue and tried to create multiple BitSet objects from each element of the array.

**BitSet objects are created on the following way:**

```
BitSet bitSetTwentyOne = BitSet.valueOf(new byte[]{21});
BitSet bitSetOneHundredSevenTeen = BitSet.valueOf(new byte[{117});
BitSet bitSetFourtyOne = BitSet.valueOf(new byte[]{41});
BitSet bitSetMinusOne = BitSet.valueOf(new byte[]{-1});
```

**The bits are printed out by using the following method:**

```
private String getBits(BitSet bitSet) {
    StringBuilder bitsBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < bitSet.length(); i++) {
        bitsBuilder.append(bitSet.get(i) == true ? 1 : 0);
    }

    return bitsBuilder.toString();
}
```

**Output:**

```
bitSetTwentyOne: 10101 but expected -> 00010101 (BitSet::length = 5)
bitSetOneHundredSevenTeen: 1010111 but expected -> 01110101 (BitSet::length = 7)
bitSetFourtyOne: 100101 but expected -> 00101001 (BitSet::length = 6)
bitSetMinusOne: 11111111 but it is as expected at least (BitSet::length = 8)
```

I want all values 8bit width even if it is needed to fill with zeros. I do not understand why it gives wrong binary values in case of converting **117** and **41**.

Comment: What does `BitSet::length()` do?

Comment: Stored as little-endian but printed big-endian - that's why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are printing the bits backwards.  Notice how your output (except for the desired leading zeros) is a mirror image of your expected input.

Using your code, passing in `4`, which should be `100`, I get `001`.  It appears that bit `0` is the least significant bit, not the most significant bit.  To correct this, loop over the indices backwards.  The reason that `-1` and `41` are correct apart from the leading zeros is that their bitset representations are palindromes.

To prepend leading zeros, subtract the `length()` from `8` and print that many zeros.  The `length()` method only returns the number of bits necessary to represent the number.  You need to code this yourself; there is no `BitSet` functionality for leading zeros.

Answer (score 3):

- `length()` delivers the *logical* length using the highest bit 1.
- `size()` would give 8.
- `cardinality()` would give the number of bit 1s.

So you should have used `size()`.

And then the bits are in *little endian* format, and you reversed it by outputting bit at 0 first.

```
private String getBits(BitSet bitSet) {
    StringBuilder bitsBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < bitSet.size(); ++i) {
        bitsBuilder.insert(0, bitSet.get(i) ? '1' : '0');
    }
    return bitsBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: `insert(0, ...)` has poor performance because all the elements have to be shifted every time. It is better to allocate `bitSet.size()` and then use `StringBuilder.setCharAt`.

Comment: @Clashsoft thanks for mentioning that; implementation matters. In fact originally I tended to change the original problem to use a `new char[8]` i.o. a `StringBuilder`.